# Adding new element to array from left rest shift one step right in java

Tags: java

My question is:
I wish to add an element to the array. 

The array length is 3 thanks to 'createArray' method

method 'addElementsToArray' adding new element 
to the position of 'this.array[0]' if rest positions in the array are used 
they shifting one step to right making the first position is empty for the new element. 
what if my array length would be equals to 10 or 100? 
Is there a way to use fewer lines of code for no matter what length of an array. 
Thank you

```
private int[] array;

public createArray(int m){
    this.array = new int[m];
}
public void addElementsToArray(int element){
        try {
            for (int i=0; i<=this.getArray().length; i++) {
                if (this.getArray()[i] == 0) {
                    this.getArray()[i] = element;
                    System.out.println("1");
                    break;
                }else if(this.getArray()[i] != 0 && this.getArray()[i + 1] == 0) {
                    int vault = this.getArray()[i];
                    if (this.getArray()[i + 1] == 0) {
                        this.getArray()[i + 1] = vault;
                        this.getArray()[i] = element;
                        System.out.println("2");
                        break;
                    }
                }else if(this.getArray()[i] != 0 && this.getArray()[i + 1] != 0) {
                    if (this.getArray()[i + 2] == 0) {
                        int vault = this.getArray()[i];
                        this.getArray()[i + 2] = this.getArray()[i + 1];
                        this.getArray()[i + 1] = vault;
                        this.getArray()[i] = element;
                        System.out.println("3");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
            System.out.println("This Stack is Full");
        }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(this.getArray()));
}
```

Comment: Yes, there is a way to use **much less** code to do this, and for any length of array.  Would you like some hints or shall I just give you a solution?

Comment: your current code doesn't work... when you initialize the array then try to add an element it will fill the whole array with that element instead of just the first.  Or was that on purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to loop through your array from first element to last looking for the first occurrence of 0. If you don't find one the array is full. If you do, use `System.arraycopy` to shift everything from 0 to the identified position 1 to the right, then insert the new element at position 0.

```
public void addElementsToArray(int element){  
  for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
  {
    if(array[i] == 0)
    {
      System.arraycopy(array, 0, array, 1, i);
      array[0] = element;
      return;
    }
  }
  throw new IllegalStateException("Array is full");
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, Mr 'SirRaffleBuffle' for your answer, only in my case my method is public void, so all I need is to change 'return;' into 'break;'.

Comment: You can `return` from a `void` method, you just don't return a value. If you `break` instead of `return` you'll always throw an `IllegalStateException`, even when the array is not full

Answer (score 0):

For your purpose Array is not best data Structure to user, Use Queue instead.

```
LinkedList<Integer> q = new LinkedList<>(); // LinkedList implements Queue interface
q.addFirst(5);        // will add element 5 at first position
q.addLast(6);        // will add element 6 at lastposition
int f = q.pollFirst();        // will give element at first position
int l = q.pollLast();        // will give element at lastposition

int ele= q.get(0);    // will give element at 0 index
```

The Queue is used to insert elements at the end of the queue and removes from the beginning of the queue. It follows FIFO concept.